# How to select this XML node and extract its attribute

Tags: c#, xml, regex, wpf, xml-parsing

I need to obtain `QueryPlanHash` value

It is at the `StmtSimple` node

How can i do that with C# .net 4.5 WPF application ?

Ty very much

So as a result i want to obtain `0xB36E2AA500333529`

I suppose it can also be done with regex

Here the some part of the XML file it is pretty big

```
<ShowPlanXML
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" Version="1.2" Build="12.0.2254.0">
    <BatchSequence> 
        <Batch>
            <Statements>
                <StmtSimple StatementText="-- First query.&#xd;&#xa;select tblRoutes.routeId,tblUsersProfile.squareId,tblUsersProfile.PathFinding,routeName,shapeType,  maxColumn, maxRow, wildPokemonCatchRatio,ZoneNumber,ZoneName,RouteOrder from tblUsersProfile,tblRoutes,tblMapSquareFormat where  UserId=756537 AND tblRoutes.routeId=tblUsersProfile.routeId and tblMapSquareFormat.routeId=tblUsersProfile.routeId and tblMapSquareFormat.squareId=tblUsersProfile.squareId" StatementId="1" StatementCompId="1" StatementType="SELECT" RetrievedFromCache="false" StatementSubTreeCost="0.00985766" StatementEstRows="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" QueryHash="0xE96598585A24E1EE" QueryPlanHash="0xB36E2AA500333529" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="120">
                    <StatementSetOptions QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false"/>
                    <QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="24" CompileTime="4" CompileCPU="4" CompileMemory="632">
                        <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0"/>
                        <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="418731" EstimatedPagesCached="209365" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="4"/>
                        <RelOp NodeId="0" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" LogicalOp="Inner Join" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="4.18e-006" AvgRowSize="80" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00985766" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row">
                            <OutputList>
```

Comment: use agilitypack or the xml parser you want, it will be more easy (and appropriate).

Comment: What is the problem? You can do it by typing code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq/Xml:

```
var doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan";

foreach (var stmnt in doc.Descendants(ns + "StmtSimple"))
{
    string value = (string)stmnt.Attribute("QueryPlanHash");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can do it with a regex :

```
var match = Regex.Match(xmlContent, "QueryPlanHash=\"([^\"]+)\"", RegexOption.CultureInvariant); 

if (match.Success) 
{
    String queryPlanHashValue = match.Groups[1].Value;  // Contains "0xB36E2AA500333529" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A super easy way to do it is to just use string split.

Example:

```
public string GetQueryPlanHash(string inputXML) {
   if(inputXML.Contains("QueryPlanHash=")) {
      var data1 = inputXML.Split(new[]{"QueryPlanHash=\""}, StringSplitOptions.None);
      return data1[1].Split('"')[0];
   }
   return null;
}
```

Another way you can do it, is to read the XML as a XmlDocument or XDocument and search for the attribute and get its value. Either using XPath or recursive search. (Can't show a good example as I've not done it in a while).

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=QueryPlanHash=")[^"]*
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/26